# I have a question about how to add a specific column value in a column with the same key value with pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am studying spark.
Is there a way to create and return a dataframe by combining playtime among rows where userId and movieId are duplicated among the columns in the table?
thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wyvx.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not able to understand the result data, by looking at the attached screenshot, I came up with this solution.

Here I am assuming I have to first select the records from duplicate records in final result aggregating playtime.

I have created two Dataframe `df` and `df1` of the Dataset and joined them.

```
>>> windowSpec  = Window.partitionBy("movieid").orderBy("userid")
>>> df1=df.withColumn("row_number",row_number().over(windowSpec))

>>> df1.show()
+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+--------+----------+
|userid|movieid|score|scoretype|playtime|duration|row_number|
+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+--------+----------+
|     3|    306|    5|        1|       0|       0|         1|
|     2|    202|    2|        2|    1800|    3600|         1|
|     7|    100|    0|        1|    3600|    3600|         1|
|     1|    102|    5|        1|       0|       0|         1|
|     1|    102|    0|        2|    1800|    3600|         2|
|     2|    204|    3|        1|       0|       0|         1|
|     1|    106|    3|        2|    3600|    3600|         1|
|     7|    700|    0|        2|     100|    3600|         1|
|     7|    700|    0|        2|     500|    3600|         2|
|     7|    700|    0|        2|     600|    3600|         3|
+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+--------+----------+

>>> df1=df1.where(df1.row_number==1)
>>> df1.show()
+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+--------+----------+
|userid|movieid|score|scoretype|playtime|duration|row_number|
+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+--------+----------+
|     3|    306|    5|        1|       0|       0|         1|
|     2|    202|    2|        2|    1800|    3600|         1|
|     7|    100|    0|        1|    3600|    3600|         1|
|     1|    102|    5|        1|       0|       0|         1|
|     2|    204|    3|        1|       0|       0|         1|
|     1|    106|    3|        2|    3600|    3600|         1|
|     7|    700|    0|        2|     100|    3600|         1|
+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+--------+----------+

>>> df=df.groupBy("userid","movieid").agg(sum("playtime"))

>>> df.show()
+------+-------+-------------+
|userid|movieid|sum(playtime)|
+------+-------+-------------+
|     1|    102|         1800|
|     2|    202|         1800|
|     7|    100|         3600|
|     2|    204|            0|
|     3|    306|            0|
|     7|    700|         1200|
|     1|    106|         3600|
+------+-------+-------------+

>>> df=df.withColumnRenamed("userid","useriddf").withColumnRenamed("movieid","movieiddf").withColumnRenamed("sum(playtime)","playtime1")
>>> df.show()
+--------+---------+-------------+
|useriddf|movieiddf|playtime1    |
+--------+---------+-------------+
|       1|      102|         1800|
|       2|      202|         1800|
|       7|      100|         3600|
|       2|      204|            0|
|       3|      306|            0|
|       7|      700|         1200|
|       1|      106|         3600|
+--------+---------+-------------+

>>> df_join=df.join(df1,df.movieiddf == df1.movieid,"inner")
>>> df_join.show()
+--------+---------+---------+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+--------+
|useriddf|movieiddf|playtime1|userid|movieid|score|scoretype|playtime|duration|
+--------+---------+---------+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+--------+
|       3|      306|        0|     3|    306|    5|        1|       0|       0|
|       2|      202|     1800|     2|    202|    2|        2|    1800|    3600|
|       7|      100|     3600|     7|    100|    0|        1|    3600|    3600|
|       1|      102|     1800|     1|    102|    5|        1|       0|       0|
|       2|      204|        0|     2|    204|    3|        1|       0|       0|
|       1|      106|     3600|     1|    106|    3|        2|    3600|    3600|
|       7|      700|     1200|     7|    700|    0|        2|     100|    3600|
+--------+---------+---------+------+-------+-----+---------+--------+--------+

>>> df_join.select("userid","movieid","score","scoretype","playtime1","duration").sort("userid").show()
+------+-------+-----+---------+---------+--------+
|userid|movieid|score|scoretype|playtime1|duration|
+------+-------+-----+---------+---------+--------+
|     1|    102|    5|        1|     1800|       0|
|     1|    106|    3|        2|     3600|    3600|
|     2|    202|    2|        2|     1800|    3600|
|     2|    204|    3|        1|        0|       0|
|     3|    306|    5|        1|        0|       0|
|     7|    100|    0|        1|     3600|    3600|
|     7|    700|    0|        2|     1200|    3600|
+------+-------+-----+---------+---------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is helpful for you.

```
# you can use groupBy + sum function
# filter if userid==1 or userid==7 (movieid is not necessary because they have distinct userid)
duplicated_user_movie = df.filter(F.col('userid')==1 or F.col('userid')==7)
duplicated_sum = duplicated_user_movie.groupBy('userid', 'movieid', 'score', 'scoretype', 'duration').agg(F.sum('playtime'))

cols = ['userid', 'movieid', 'score', 'scoretype', 'playtime', 'duration']
duplicated_sum = duplicated_sum.toDF(*cols) # change column orders

df = df.filter((F.col('userid')!=1) & (F.col('userid')!=7))
df = df.union(duplicated_sum) # concat two dataframes
df = df.orderBy('userid') # sort by userid
```